# Free opc server toolkit in a commercial setting

Tags: instruments, opc

Has anyone here used a free opc server toolkit such as fatrat or lightopc in a commercial setting before? Were there any additional costs involved?

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't use lightopc. There is no DA3 support.

Most PLC manufacturers which sell OPC Servers, give their OPC Servers free with their protocol license.
In these OPC Servers there are (some) simulation possibilities. Most commercial environments have a CD with the PLC protocol drivers somewhere. You don't need the license, you just need the server.

Also Matrikon has a free OPC Simulator available for download. This is my favourite tool to test with OPC.

Check www.opcfoundation.org for more information about OPC simulation.